# getting the file size with pycurl

Tags: python, pycurl

I want to write a downloader with python and I use PycURL as my library, but I got a problem.
I can't get the size of the file wich I wanna download. Here is part of my code :

```
import pycurl
url = 'http://www.google.com'
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
print c.getinfo(c.CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD)
c.perform()
```

When I test this code in python shell, it's ok but when I write it as a function and run it, it gives me -1 instead of the size.
What is the problem?

(code's been edited)

Comment: Is this _exactly_ what you're running? Because you _still_ have the `getinfo` call before `perform`.

Comment: No, I tested your code too. But I preferred to keep my problem in the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `pycurl` documentation on the Curl object:

> The getinfo method should not be called unless perform has been called
>   and finished.

You're calling `getinfo` before you've called `perform`.

Here is a simplified version of your example, does this work?

```
import pycurl

url = 'http://www.google.com'
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.perform()
print c.getinfo(c.CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD)
```

You should see the HTML content followed by the size.

Comment: Actually I'd tested it and again it gave me '-1.0'!

Comment: Can you update your code to show what you're actually testing, because what's in the question won't work at all.

Comment: Yeah, I made mistakes in question text, its code is edited now. Did you test your answer? It's weird but still it doesn't work!

Comment: I _definitely_ tested this, and it's still working now :) There must be some other issue at work here; what OS are you on, what Python version, are you behind a proxy etc? Try `python -c "import os; print os.__file__"` and do the same import & print from within the interpreter: are they both the same Python version?

Comment: I use Windows7 and my python version is 2.7.2 .I'm using internet via a VPN connection in my university.

Answer (score 4):

This answer adds the missing `c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1)` and is otherwise the same as the one given some months ago:

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://www.alfe.de')
c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1)
c.perform()
c.getinfo(c.CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD)
```

Calling `c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1)` before calling `c.perform()` avoids downloading the contents of the file ("No Body", but all headers).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding debug to see what happens actually. After you created curl make this:

```
def curl_debug(debug_type, msg):
    print("debug: %s %s" % (repr(debug_type), repr(msg)))

c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, curl_debug)
```